# 8-pin JTAG for Marvell Sheeva board

Tags: arm, jtag

I am looking for different option of interfacing to the JTAG port on a PogoPlug board. I have found the picture below which has silkscreen (my board doesn't),
I have used JTAG before, but it was built into the board (using an FTDI chip).

I am not quite sure what type of dongle can I possibly purchase.

I also have a few devices which could be made to do the job, I think I could use
[usbprog-jtag](http://code.google.com/p/usbprog-jtag/) code on an Arduino, however that will also require a level-shifter (which I don't have). I have a few other devices, including an [mbed](http://mbed.org) board
(cortex-m3) and an [Econotag](http://mc1322x.devl.org) (arm7).

Is there a cross-platform example that I could compile with a customized GPIO mapping header and use that with OpenOCD?

I don't have a parallel port on my new machine, though I don't really feel like
fiddling with parport any more, a USB dongle device is a preference really.

I know that FT2232 chip can be used for JTAG using libftdi, however I only have
a FT232R cable, I suppose that cannot be use really, is that right? Though I manged
to run `bitbang` command from libftdi. Probably the FT232R is missing some important pins that would make it usable as JTAG tool ...

*Update 1:* I have had a conversation with one person who suggested that there should
be a way of using FT232 in bitbang mode, since you can set TX/RX to be GPIO and
apparently [this blog](http://exmrclean.blogspot.com/2009/05/burning-avr-boot-loader-with-usb-ttl.html) describes how to use the FTDI cable as AVR ISP.

[image: pogoplug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to go with the [Bus Blaster](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Blaster), because it looks like the most flexible and inexpensive JTAG adaptor out there. It features a CPLD which does most of the work and can be re-programmed also.

[image: bb]

Answer (score 1):

I use an [Olimex USB OCD JTAG dongle](http://www.olimex.com/dev/arm-usb-ocd.html).
But, [I've also had some success with the Bus Pirate](http://blog.hodgepig.org/2010/04/13/545/) (both using OpenOCD on linux)

Comment: yeah, I had been told that just about any JTAG dongle should work, however the question regarding DIY still remains unanswered ;(

Comment: Take a look at the driver layer in OpenOCD or urjtag for examples of how to hook up your own JTAG device, eg. https://github.com/cktben/urjtag/blob/master/urjtag/src/tap/cable/ft2232.c